# Drupal 7 ajax and session

Tags: ajax, session, drupal

I have created a .module file which includes a form and an ajax call back. Here is a simple code of the .module file:

```
function form_registration_form($form, &$form_state) {
      $form['registration']['email'] = array(
        '#type'      => 'textfield',
        '#required'  => TRUE,
        '#size'      => 44,
        '#maxlength' => '80',
        '#attributes'=> array('placeholder' => 'Email','data-email'=>'','data-min-chars'=>'5'),
      );
      $form['registration']['password'] = array(
        '#type'      => 'password',
        '#required'  => TRUE,
        '#size'      => 44,
        '#maxlength' => '80',
        '#attributes'=> array('placeholder' => 'Password'),
      );
      $form['registration']['submit'] = array(
        '#value'     => 'SIGN IN',
        '#type'      => 'submit',
        '#submit'    => array('form_registration_handler'),
        );
      return $form;
}
and in the function form_registration_handler I create a session (name it test).
Here is the ajax menu call back function:

function mymodule_menu() {

    $items['ajax/innerAction'] = array(
        'title' => 'Browser Inner Action',
        'page callback' => 'innerActionCallBack',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

function innerActionCallBack() {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    drupal_session_start();
    print session_id();
}
```

This function is used on my page.tpl.php file to create an ajax to server. 
    The problem here is when I call the ajax, the session id is different when 
    I refresh the browser and I can not retreive the Session test that I created earlier.
    Do you know what is happening here. Any helps are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have figured out the answer. I have to login the user into Drupal first so that Drupal can retrieve the correct sessionID.